# How can I display all possible values in a SuggestBox

Tags: gwt

I would like to display all possible values in a SuggestBox.

Naturally, I have the following code (settingName is a SuggestBox)

```
settingName.getTextBox().addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
      settingName.showSuggestionList();
    }
  });
```

Unfortunately, the suggestbox displays anything. Of course, the settingName is associated to an oracle with several values inside it.

Am I crazy ?

According to the documentation :

> public void showSuggestionList()
>
> ```
> Show the current list of suggestions.
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the defaults to show by [`suggestOracle.setDefaultSuggestionsFromText(..)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MultiWordSuggestOracle.html#setDefaultSuggestionsFromText%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: Fwiw:  suggestDefaultSuggestionsFromText is in the MultiWordSuggestOracle API, not the base SuggestOracle.  But this answer is corect to that end.

Answer (score 4):

When showing the list, the `SuggestBox` will ask the oracle for values to show. If the text box is empty, then `requestDefaultSuggestions` will be called (which by default calls `requestSuggestions`).